# How to get the element from an html function call?

Tags: angularjs

I have one function to update multiple progress bars :

```
$scope.updateExpProgressBar = function(unit) {
        return ((unit.exp * /*here I need the max width of the progress bar*/) / unit.nextLevel) + "px";
    };
```

HTML example:

```
<div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-bar-value" style="width: {{updateExpProgressBar(selectedUnit)}}"></div>
</div>
```

The thing is that these progress bars don't have the same width, and I don't want to create one function for every one of them.

Comment: Why can't you pass the max width to the function, too? Also, I'd expect that a progress bar's style has width expressed in `%` of the outer container, then it's easy to change the width without changing any code.

Comment: Simple answer - use directive. Name id 'progressBar', create your events and ngClick in its template. You will have $element object in your `link` method corresponding to the current element.

Comment: @9000 Because some of their width can vary. (fo example if there is a scroll bar or not)

Comment: @MikeGrabowski Sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @Elfayer: you can vary container element's width as you please, and have its child div the scrollbar always vary from 0% to 100%.

Comment: @9000 Right, I didn't get you the first time, sounds even simplier to fix.